# Copy an archived blob to an online tier

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I need to copy a blob from archive tier to the hot tear in another container. If I'm using StartCopy method I'm getting **"This operation is not permitted on an archived blob"** error. Here is my code:

```
CloudBlockBlob blobSource = (CloudBlockBlob)item; 
CloudBlockBlob blobTarget = ArchiveContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobSource.Name);
blobTarget.StartCopy(blobSource);
```

It should be possible to do based on [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-rehydration?tabs=azure-portal#copy-an-archived-blob-to-an-online-tier), but I didn't find any code sample. Is it possible to do with Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob, or I have to use REST API for that?

I'm using Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob NuGet package v.11.1.7

Comment: Since there is [an option to pass a rehydrate policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.startcopy?view=azure-dotnet-legacy) I assume it is possible. Have you tried investigating the additional parameters accepted by `StartCopy`?

Comment: @Crowcoder: Thank you! There are extra parameters for such task.

Answer (score 2):

As @Crowcoder suggested I checked parameters for StartCopy method and found that I need:

```
blobTarget.StartCopy(blobSource, StandardBlobTier.Hot, RehydratePriority.Standard);
```

Comment: How long did it take? I keep seeing in the docs that it can take a few hours, is that accurate in your use case?