# Azure blob Storage: Copy blobs with access tier ARCHIVE within the same Azure storage account is not working

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm using the [startCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.startcopy?view=azure-java-legacy#com_microsoft_azure_storage_blob_CloudBlockBlob_startCopy_final_CloudBlockBlob_) API from azure-storage java sdk version 8.6.5 to copy blobs between containers within the same storage account. As per the docs, it will copy a block blob's contents, properties, and metadata to a new block blob. Does this also mean source and destination access tier will match ?

```
String copyJobId = cloudBlockBlob.startCopy(sourceBlob);
```

If the source blob access tier is ARCHIVE, I am getting the following exception -

```
com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: This operation is not permitted on an archived blob.
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:87) ~[azure-storage-8.6.5.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.StorageRequest.materializeException(StorageRequest.java:305) ~[azure-storage-8.6.5.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:196) ~[azure-storage-8.6.5.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob.startCopy(CloudBlob.java:791) ~[azure-storage-8.6.5.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlob.startCopy(CloudBlockBlob.java:302) ~[azure-storage-8.6.5.jar:?]
    at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlob.startCopy(CloudBlockBlob.java:180) ~[azure-storage-8.6.5.jar:?]
```

As shown below, I used startCopy API to copy all blobs in container02(src) to container03(destination).  Blob with access tier ARCHIVE failed and also test1.txt blob's access tier is not same as in source.

I just want to confirm if this is expected or I am not using the right API and need to set these properties explicitly if I need both source and destination to look same??

Thanks in Advance!!!

[image]

Comment: This seems related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62759750/copy-an-archived-blob-to-an-online-tier.  I think you need to ensure you pass a RehydratePriority parameter for archived items.

Comment: Adding RehydratePriority parameter worked. Thanks @Bryan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** Blob with access tier ARCHIVE failed

You cannot execute the `startCopy` operation when the access tier is `ARCHIVE`.

Please refer to this [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-storage-tiers?tabs=azure-portal#archive-access-tier):

> While a blob is in archive storage, the blob data is offline and can't be read, overwritten, or modified. To read or download a blob in archive, you must first rehydrate it to an online tier. You can't take snapshots of a blob in archive storage. However, the blob metadata remains online and available, allowing you to list the blob, its properties, metadata, and blob index tags. Setting or modifying the blob metadata while in archive is not allowed; however you may set and modify the blob index tags. For blobs in archive, the only valid operations are GetBlobProperties, GetBlobMetadata, SetBlobTags, GetBlobTags, FindBlobsByTags, ListBlobs, SetBlobTier, CopyBlob, and DeleteBlob.

**2.** test1.txt blob's access tier is not same as in source.

The access tier of the copied blob may be related to the default access tier.

[image]

**Solution:**

You may need to move the files from archive storage to the hot or cool access tier. Or you can use this [API](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.microsoft.azure/azure-storage/8.4.0/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/CloudBlockBlob.html#startCopy-com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlob-java.lang.String-boolean-com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.StandardBlobTier-com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.RehydratePriority-com.microsoft.azure.storage.AccessCondition-com.microsoft.azure.storage.AccessCondition-com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobRequestOptions-com.microsoft.azure.storage.OperationContext-) and specify `standardBlobTier` and `rehydratePriority`:

```
public final String startCopy(final CloudBlockBlob sourceBlob, String contentMd5, boolean syncCopy, final StandardBlobTier standardBlobTier, RehydratePriority rehydratePriority, final AccessCondition sourceAccessCondition, final AccessCondition destinationAccessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext opContext)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Frank for a detailed answer.